# map_df with two arguments and a list of dataframes

Tags: r, purrr

I read csv files and get a list of dataframes

```
wczytaj.csv.new <- function (kotl, rok) {
  sciezka.df <- paste0 ("F:/ZIMA-NEW-dane/", kotl, "-NEW", "/")
  M601_M_flist <- list.files (sciezka.df, pattern = paste0("^(M601-M-)(",  rok,  ").*\\.csv$") )
  All <- lapply(M601_M_flist,function(i){
    read_delim(paste0(sciezka.df, i), locale = locale(encoding = "cp1250", decimal_mark = "."), na = c("***", "NA"), show_col_types = FALSE) 
  })
  return(All)
}
df.csv.new <- wczytaj.csv.new ("A5", 2023)
```

I want to create a function that I will use in map_df but it will have two arguments, concept below

```
glowne.zuzycia.new <- function(x, kotl) {

 if (kotl == ""A5) {
spec == 10 } else {
spec= 100}

  x <- x %>% select(
    Czas,
    `[LC1] Energia [J]`/ spec,
    `[LC2] Temp. zasilania [°C]`,
    `[LC2] Temp. powrotu [°C]`,
    `[LC2] Moc akt. [W]`,
    `[LC2] Temp. dodatkowa [°C]`,
 )
}

df.new.3 <- map_df(df.csv.new, glowne.zuzycia.new ("A5"))
```

Comment: Try `map_df(df.csv.new, glowne.zuzycia.new, kotl = "A5")` or `map_df(df.csv.new, ~ glowne.zuzycia.new(.x, "A5"))`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.